# I accidentally created a git local branch called --track, how can I delete it?

Tags: git

I mistyped a git command which resulted in the creation of a local branch called, '--track'.

I've tried the following:

```
git branch -m --track delme
(this renames the current branch to delme, not the branch called --track)

git checkout --track
> fatal: --track needs a branch name

git branch -d --track
(does nothing, reports nothing)

git branch -D --track
(also does nothing)

git branch -d "--track"
(also does nothing
```

How can I delete this branch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git branch -d -- --track
```

In general, `--` tells git to treat all subsequent command-line arguments as non-options.

EDIT: See the comments for clarification regarding how git uses `--`.

Comment: Actually, `--` tells pretty much *any* Unix command to treat all subsequent command-line arguments as non-options.

Comment: But many git commands use `--` as a separator between revision(s) and pathspec arguments (neither of which are options)... but not in the case of `git branch`.